# looping in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to do looping process inside stored procedure to insert max number of records

Comment: explain. You want to know sytnax of loop? or you want to file DB with temporary records?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to bring down a database :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should start with the fact that the maximum numbers of records in a table is actually the number of records inserted when the database gets its maximum disk size, but this is not a constant, because some different table might get bigger and yours has less capacity.... So if you don't have a maximum database size it will grow until the disk is full and so on...

There is no such thing like maximum number of rows in a table. You can insert while you have free space in the database file/files.

You have to be a little more specific about your database/server configuration.

I guess you are not asking about that, but infinite loop in tsql is just

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
      INSERT  ..
END
```